# Deleting identical lines

Tags: c#

I have a List <> containing the IP addresses obtained from the xlsx document. I need to delete the same and at the same time delete both in the sheet and in the Excel-file.
I do this with the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ip.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ip.Count; j++)
    {
        if(j != i)              
        {
            if (ip[i] == ip[j])
            {
                ep.Workbook.Worksheets[1].DeleteRow(j + 1);
                ip.RemoveAt(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but does not remove all the same addresses. We have to re-run the file and the second time he has already cleaned up the rest of the repetitions. How to make it so that he immediately cleaned all the same elements? I do not understand where I was wrong. thank

Comment: Why don't you retrieve and make distinct and then append?

Comment: To remove duplicates in the list, you can do `ip = ip.Distinct();`

Comment: invert your loops; start with `ip.Count` and decrement the index value

Comment: @SamW, I can't do that. Since the file values of the form ip: port. (One ip can have different ports) I break them down into two list <>, and then delete the row with them from the Excel spreadsheet.
And if I use Distinct (), I will not be able to remove the same port elements. also in Excle there will be garbage

Comment: Is this uploaded to an application or just a workbook you download? Why not just use some classic VBA?

Comment: Your loops are comparing the same items more than necessary. I think you can just start off the second loop with `int j = i + 1` to avoid that (and then you can also remove the first `if`). You also need to start at the end and work backwards if you're removing items from the list (otherwise the indexes are no longer correct as soon as something is removed).

Comment: @RubensFarias Thank You

Comment: @DmitryAfteeer you should include that information in your question. Also, what is the type of your list? Is it a string, or something else?

Comment: For your recent question : With 2 simple List<int> like listDuplicate = {0,1,1,2,3,3} and ListIndex = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Define what will be the Expected output for each of those list. Step by step how would you manually proceed? i will recommend to Always read [ask] before posting. They are great tool to make simple and clear question. Proof reading, expected output and input are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code might be that every time you remove something from `ip` the indexes shift and at every subsequent remove you're not removing what you actually think you are. You have to do this separately from iterating through the colletion you're doing changes to. Furthermore, LINQ might help you getting all the duplicates in a bit more elegant way.

```
var duplicateRecords = ip
    // Preserve the original index within the collection
    .Select((x, i) => new { Ip = x, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Ip)
     // Get only those records that repeat within the collection
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
     // Skip the first record as we want to keep a single record of each duplicate group
    .SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1))
    .ToList();

foreach (var duplicate in duplicateRecords) {
  ep.Workbook.Worksheets[1].DeleteRow(duplicate.Index + 1);
  // Removing from the 'ip' list here is not an option as it would shift the indexes
}
ip = ip.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this
**Note**: `WhateverTypeYourIpIs` should override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` or provide an `IEqualityComparer<WhateverTypeYourIpIs>` to `HashSet`

```
HashSet<WhateverTypeYourIpIs> hashSet = new HashSet<WhateverTypeYourIpIs>();
for(int i = 0; i < ip.Count;)
{
    if(hashSet.Contains(ip[i]))
    {
        ep.Workbook.Worksheets[1].DeleteRow(i + 1);
        ip.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        hashSet.Add(ip[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```